# Superposition principle in electrostatics: Experiments

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, experimental-physics, superposition, linear-systems

I understand that the superposition principle in electrostatics is consistent with experience and therefore is not very questionable. However, is it possible to perform a direct experimental test of this principle? Has it been done? Failing direct test, is it possible to quantify (and put limit on) possible violations based on indirect evidence?

PS: There are questions on this site about possible theoretical derivations, intuitive understanding, etc. of the superposition principle. This question is about experimental justification.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this principle should not be very hard. Let's say you can measure the potential difference between a point in space and the ground. Now if you add an additional charge to the setup this charge will change the potential you measure. If $V(\mathbf{r})$ is known for the additional charge, then you can immediately see whether superposition holds or not.